# Profiling tools for GUI

Tags: qt, profiling

I'm trying to profile a Qt application that uses a lot of animations. Platform is XP.

I am very interested in compating CPU utilization between runs to get a high level view of how changes in the app effect cpu usage.

I have tried VTune and Quantify.

I can't seem to configure VTune to do what I want. The percentages I am able to generate don't correspond to total CPU usage.

When I use quantify, it generates a call graph but it never shows the application so I'm not sure if I'm setting it up correctly.

Anyone have suggestions? Other tools welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Qt are you using?  If 4.5, have you considered the new profiling abilities of `QUnitTest`?  It would be a bit of a mangle to use it for a whole application, but you might be able to get it to work.